# etcd in CoreOS not listening on port 4001

Tags: systemd, coreos

When starting etcd in CoreOS it does not listen to port 4001.

Only when starting from the prompt:

`$ sudo systemctl start etcd.service
$ ps aux|grep etcd
etcd      9364  0.1  0.8 267980  4880 ?        Ssl  05:43   0:00 /usr/bin/etcd
$ sudo lsof -i|grep LISTEN
systemd    1 root   26u  IPv6  14958      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
$ sudo -u etcd /usr/bin/etcd
$ sudo lsof -i|grep LISTEN
systemd    1 root   26u  IPv6  14958      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
etcd    9387 etcd    6u  IPv6 194642      0t0  TCP *:4001 (LISTEN)
etcd    9387 etcd    7u  IPv6 194643      0t0  TCP *:afs3-callback (LISTEN)`

Comment: Things to check: Running the initscript through `bash -x` (if it is a bash script), ogling the environment and command line options of the process.

Comment: Are yiu saying it fails to start automatically when the system starts ? If so are there any relevant log messages ?

Answer (score 2):

etcd and fleet only start by default if specified in a cloud-config parameter:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
```

If you have this in your cloud-config already, journalctl -u etcd should indicate why.

Comment: Thanks.  journalctl -u etcd was indicating that no other hosts could be reached in the cluster. I had been starting and stopping servers with the same unique discovery token in cloud-config. **By using a new unique discovery token solved the problem.**